# Opencart 3.x generating SEO-Friendly links for 'Search on homepage' and 'admin page'

Tags: php, html, search, seo, opencart

Working with opencart 3.x. I was thinking of changing .htaccess, seo_url, I wouldn't want to mess with the tables in mysql if it's possible. Three questions I can't find a solution to. I'm stuck on these two, trying to make them SEO friendly & having a block html on the php page. Any help would be nice, thanks.

current link:

```
https://www.-----.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=...
```

Q: 1) How to get SEO link to be just

```
https://www.-----.com/search
```

admin current link
https://www.-----.com/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&user_token=...

Q: 2) How to get SEO link to be just

```
https://www.-----.com/admin/dashboard
```

Q: 3) How can I create a block html on opencart manually in FZilla? I like write them in the actually files instead of modifying it and screw up the store.

Comment: Please ask 1 question at a time.

1. Look for an extension.
2. Why do you want this? I don't think there's any point.
3. You mean modify the twig files? They are in the template folder.

Answer (score 1):

## FRONTEND

For frontend (catalog) I have 2 solutions: long and short.

1. Long.

- first, add support for custom urls in `catalog/controller/statup/seo_url.php` on `line 103` after the closing `}`

```php
else {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['route']) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

    if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
    } else {
        $url = '';
    }
}
```

Then run the following MySQL code in your phpMyAdmin. It will populate the custom urls.

```sql
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'product/search', 'search');
```

You can also add all the other custom urls as well.

```sql
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'common/home', '');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/wishlist', 'wishlist');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/account', 'my-account');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'checkout/cart', 'shopping-cart');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'checkout/checkout', 'checkout');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/login', 'login');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/logout', 'logout');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/order', 'order-history');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/newsletter', 'newsletter');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'product/special', 'specials');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/account', 'affiliates');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/voucher', 'voucher');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'product/manufacturer', 'brands');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'information/contact', 'contact-us');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/return/add', 'request-return');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'information/sitemap', 'sitemap');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/forgotten', 'forgot-password');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/download', 'downloads');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/return', 'returns');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/transaction', 'transactions');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/register', 'create-account');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'product/compare', 'compare-products');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/edit', 'edit-account');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/password', 'change-password');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/address', 'address-book');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'account/reward', 'reward-points');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/edit', 'edit-affiliate-account');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/password', 'change-affiliate-password');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/payment', 'affiliate-payment-options');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/tracking', 'affiliate-tracking-code');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/transaction', 'affiliate-transactions');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/logout', 'affiliate-logout');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/forgotten', 'affiliate-forgot-password');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/register', 'create-affiliate-account');
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'affiliate/login', 'affiliate-login');
```

2. Short.

Just install SEO Module URL and set it up. You will have all custom URLs edited automatically for you and you can then customize them as you wish via the admin panel.

[image]

[SEO Module URL](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29764&filter_download_id=41&filter_rating=1)

## BACKEND

For backend (admin) OpenCart does not implement SEO Url functionality. You can do it on your own, but it requires a bit more coding to be done.

Basically you need to reproduce the `catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php` in admin folder

and register this in `system/config/admin.php`

```php
$_['action_pre_action'] = array(
...
'startup/seo_url'
```

You will also need to add the custom urls to the seo_url table in the DB.

```sql
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('0', '1', 'common/dashboard', 'dashboard');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, small typo, missed 's' in $query->num_rows